# Backbone Dynamically created 'el' not binding events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

Like many other users out here I have a problem with `el` and events. In my situation I have tested multiple solutions including, using the default `el` (just `<div></div>`) setting `tagName`, setting `el` to a selector using a jQuery selector and waiting for the DOM to be ready. Each of these solutions have failed at binding the events and all but the default `el` and `tagName` have failed at generating html.
Relevant code:

View

```
$ ->
   class Aggregator.Views.Streams.StreamView extends Backbone.View
      template:JST["backbone/templates/stream"]
      el: $('.item')
      events:
       "click div" : "testing"
      initialize: (model)->
       console.log @el
       _.bindAll this , 'render'
       @model.bind 'change', @render
       @model.view = @
       @render()
       @delegateEvents()
      render: ->
       $(@el).html  "test"
       console.log @el
       @
      testing: ->
       alert "EVENT"
       #@model.clear()
```

Function that calls view (extracted from another view)

```
view = new Aggregator.Views.Streams.StreamView({model: stream})
    console.log view.el
    $(@el).append view.render().el
```

I'm a bit confused, I have set `el` but it either doesn't create or it doesn't bind events. I've tried waiting for the DOM to load and passing `el` to the constructor but no success. Any help on my most likely obvious mistake would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry i'm not comfortable with coffeescript, though i think i recognised your event hash

```
events: {
  "click div" : "testing"
}
```

and i bet you are trying to bind this testing function to the click on your general view element?
there is the problem.

what your click event actually does (selector-wise) is:

```
$('div', viewElement).click(fn);
```

meaning, you don't target the viewElement div but div's INSIDE your view element.

if you want to bind to the general view element itself,
define an event without a selector

in your case:

```
events: {
  "click" : "testing"
}
```

Comment: that works! i had assumed that "click" would be relative to the document not to the view element. thanks for the explanation.

Comment: well that assumption is wrong, the event hash is always scoped within the view's element, and thus, click without anything will bind to the el itself, click with something behind it will search inside the el.