# How can I bind events to the 'el' in backbone that is dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bind

I'm having some trouble binding events to a dynamically created element using backbone.

Here is the code for the backbone view that generated the element. ('.modal')

```
var MakeModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#btn-make-modal',

    events: {
        'click': 'makeModal'
    },

    makeModal: function () {
        $('body').html('<div class="modal"><div class="modal-close">&times;</div>Close me! I\'m a modal!</div>');
    }
});
new MakeModalView();
```

Here is the View that controls the dynamically created element:

```
var ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.modal',

    events: {
        'click .modal-close': 'closeModal'
    },

    closeModal: function () {
        this.$el.remove();
    }
});
new ModalView();
```

The problem I'm having is that the view that controls the dynamically created element (ModalView) is not binding events to that dynamic element. ('.modal')

**How can I bind elements to a dynamically created 'el' in backbone?**

I've looked at the following solutions:

[Backbone Dynamically created 'el' not binding events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452544/backbone-dynamically-created-el-not-binding-events)

[How do you create Backbone views with an 'el' that was dynamically created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142451/how-do-you-create-backbone-views-with-an-el-that-was-dynamically-created)

But I still can't seem to figure out how to attach the events to the dynamic element.

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate how this behavior works. http://jsfiddle.net/6wzzk/3/

Comment: Why don't you create your `ModalView` in the `makeModal` method? Because then your closing will work http://jsfiddle.net/6wzzk/4/. And for me a method which is called `makeModal` sounds like the right place to create the `ModalView`.

Comment: @nemesv That seems like the best solution to me.  You should post that as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate a Backbone.View then Backbone tries to get its `el` and do the event subscription (delegation). So if the `el` is not in the DOM yet the events won't fire.

In your case because you are creating the model with the `makeModal` method just move the `ModalView` creation there:

```
makeModal: function () {
    $('body').html('<div class="modal"><div class="modal-close">&times;</div>');
    new ModalView();
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wzzk/4/).

Anyway the creation of the `ModalView` should be the `MakeModalView` responsibility and doing that in the `makeModal` method sounds like the right place to do it.

Comment: You can also create the dynamic `el`-ement in the `initialize` function of your view OR even in the `render` routine. Seems cleaner that way.